# Transparent threejs shader

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a sphere transparent. Here is my code:

```
var material_sphere1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffaa00, shading: THREE.FlatShading, opacity: 0 } );
```

This does not make the sphere transparent (opacity:0) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try also setting `transparent: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A material is only transparent when both the opacity and the transparent property (set this to true) are set. By the way, if you set the opacity to 0, you won't see your object at all.

Comment: Oops, just saw that Icemonster replied in a comment.